# How to get a python list that is converted to a string, assigned to attributes in a struct in C++

Tags: python, c++, pointers, struct, enums

Okay I am editing my original post. Apologies for not being clear enough earlier. I am relatively new to the developer role, specifically C,C++,Python and Embedded Linux.

There is a python list `plist = [2,434]`

This data is sent to another program written in C++ using socket programming.

```
plist = str(plist)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STRREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost',12345))
sock.send(plist.encode('utf-8'))
sock.close()
```

Now this data is received by the C++ program as a string.
I just made a sample string as follows to give you an idea what I am getting at the C++ end.

`const char* construct= "[2,434]";`

Now I am trying to assign the two numbers, 2 and 434, to `playerType` and `playerID` respectively, which are part of the following structure called **PLAYER_HEADER**.

```
typedef enum
{
    START,
    STOP,
    PAUSE,
    RECORD
}PLAYER_TYPE;

typedef struct
{
    PLAYER_TYPE playerType;
    unsigned long playerID;
}PLAYER_HEADER;
```

So far I've tried this approach, where I am typecasting the string to a struct type.

```
        PLAYER_HEADER* p= (PLAYER_HEADER* ) construct;
        player = p->playerType;
        cout<<(char)player<<endl;
```

But this prints only '**[**' which is the first character of **[2,434]**

I would like to know why this is happening.
Is there a way I can get the rest of the data?

I get that I have typecasted as a character.
My end goal is to assign the two numbers to `playerType` and `playerID` .

Is there any other way I can do this? Or is there a concept in C++ I need too understand to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to parse the string. `std::stringstream` is one option.

Comment: Please, study the C++ language in some basic level first...

Comment: @SergeRoussak I am quite new to it, and studying. Would like to know where it's going wrong.

Comment: It is historically the low level (system) language. So, there are no such the constructions like mentioned by you. On the other hand, to answer your question, too many things should be explained. In other words, a question should be asked in a right way in order to get right answer.

Comment: @SergeRousak Fair enough. I didn't want to mix topics, for fear of making the question too complex. I have edited my original post. I used incorrect terminologies. My apologies. By construct I mean the format of the character array data that I am receiving. I am trying to get 2 values that are coming through socket communication in the form of a string. But I haven't figured out how to extract data from something that looks like a python list in C++ and assign it to a struct

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I will try this and come back. Have edited my original post to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a powerful language but part of that power is to let you do things that aren't "correct". The way you are trying to cast a `char *` to a `PLAYER_HEADER*` just doesn't work as you are expecting it to. You need to *parse* the string, ignoring parts you don't want and converting the parts you keep to the correct data type.

One way to do this is with `std::stringstream`:

```
PLAYER_HEADER player;
std::istringstream ss(construct);
int temp;
ss.ignore(100, '['); // Skip [
if (ss >> temp) {
    player.playerType = (PLAYER_TYPE)temp;
    ss.ignore(100, ','); // Skip ,
    if (ss >> player.playerID) {
        // Success. Do something.
    }
}
```

Another option is regex:

```
PLAYER_HEADER player;
std::smatch match;
std::regex re(R"(\[(\d+),(\d+)\])");
std::string construct_str(construct);
if (std::regex_search(construct_str, match, re)) {
    playerType = (PLAYER_TYPE)std::stoi(match[1]);
    playerID   = std::stoi(match[2]);
    // Success. Do something.
}
```

There are still other ways, but the main point is that you need to learn why your casting doesn't work. With your code:

```
PLAYER_HEADER* p= (PLAYER_HEADER* ) construct;
player = p->playerType;
cout<<(char)player<<endl;
```

`p` points to the first char in `"[2,434]"` which is a `[`. Then `playerType` most likely has an offset of `0` in the struct so `player` also ends up pointing to the `[`. Then when you print it as a `char` you get `[`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped. I was able to go through stringstream last night. Very useful stuff. I made a simple approach. Since I am getting the stream in the format [a,b]. I just parsed the first 4 items. i.e ```ss >>character>>a>>character>>b;``` This helped me get the desired result. I then assigned 'a' and 'b' to ```p->playerType``` and '''p->playerID''' . I do have one question though. If I tried to parse as ```ss>>character>>p->p->playerType>>character>>p_playerID;``` I get an error. Why is that? I worked around that error using 'a' and 'b' temporary variables.

Comment: Correcting  that last line of code ```ss>>character>>p->playerType>>character>>p->playerID;```
Any idea why i would get an error on this statement? I used temp variables 'a' and 'b' to get around this limitation.

Comment: @JoeRace `istream` does not know how to read a type `PLAYER_TYPE`. You can fix this by overloading the extraction operator for that type: `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& i, PLAYER_TYPE& pt) { int temp; if (i >> temp) pt = (PLAYER_TYPE)temp; return i}`

Comment: Okay I will need to go through that topic -operator overloading, before I can wrap my head around this code. I shall bookmark this. It is useful.